# Simple Banking program. Not sure how to do read only/create input box/ other basic errors noted

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I will provide the attached form and code(which is mostly complete I hope). I've Been struggling all day as I'm new to this. Been forever since I worked with VB. Thanks for ANY help or guidance.

The classes are supposed to be read only.Class properties are:

- •Balance:Holds the current account balance. ReadOnly, Double. Need
  member variable to save the value I used (dblBalance) 
  •IntRate: Holds
  the interest rate for the period. Need member variable: (dblIntRate)

•Interest:  Holds the interest earned for the current period. 
   ReadOnly, (dblInterest)

•Transactions: Holds the number of
   transactions for the current period. ReadOnly.  using e  intTrans+=1.

**Methods needed** : Calc interest, Withdraw, deposits. Apparent the first step is to get the interest rate input. I think it should be in the form_load event w/ input box.

1) Allows Deposits

2) Allows Withdrawals

3) Calculate interest rate which I'm assuming is (dblInterestEarned = dblBalance*(dblIntRate/12))

4) Reports current number of transactions at any time - intTrans+=1. and obviously exit

*Edit I just think I screwed up really bad and made it harder than it should have been. So tired I apologize. Any step in the right direction is appreciated I'd like to figure this out today***

### Form[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/frw6o.jpg  (may be wrong?)

```
Public Class Class1
'Create member variables for properties

Private dblBalance As Double
Private dblIntRate As Double
Private dblInterest As Double
Private intTrans As Integer
Private dblMakeWithdrawal As Double
Private dblMakeDeposit As Double
Private dblInterestEarned As Double




'Create property procedures
Public Property Balance As Double
    Get
        Return dblBalance
    End Get

    Set(value As Double)
        dblBalance = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property IntRate As Double
    Get
        Return dblIntRate
    End Get

    Set(value As Double)
        dblIntRate = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property InterestTotal As Double
    Get
        Return InterestTotal
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        InterestTotal = value '''''''*expression recursively calls property interest total error
    End Set
End Property


''trying to 
'''calculate the amount of interest for the current period, 
''' stores this value in the Interest property, and adds it to the Balance property.
Public Sub addInterest(ByVal addInterest As Integer)
    dblInterestEarned = dblBalance * (dblIntRate / 12)
End Sub


''trying to add deposit
Public Sub addDeposit(ByVal addDeposit As Double)
    dblMakeDeposit += addDeposit

End Sub

'''''to withdraw
Public Sub subtractWithdrawl(ByVal subtractWithdrawal As Double)
    If dblMakeWithdrawal >= subtractWith() Then
        dblMakeWithdrawal -= subtractWith()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No sufficient balance")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function subtractWith() As Double
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

End Class



Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim dblMakeWithdrawal As Double

Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
    Dim dblMakeDeposit As Double


    '''''how to capture inputs from the form load??
    'Add Deposit
    dblMakeDeposit = CDbl(InputBox("Please enter deposit if you have any"))

End Sub

Private Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click
    Dim dblBalance As Integer

    dblMakeWithdrawal = CDbl(InputBox("Please enter an amount to withdraw")
    If dblBalance <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insufficient funds")
    End If
End Sub





Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '''This is where to put the input box when the form loads? 
    MessageBox.Show"Please enter current interest")
    ''how to store?





End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim dblInterTrans As Integer

     dblInterest = dblintTrans+=1.
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Function dblintTrans() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: SO is geared towards distinct, concrete questions (one per post).  this sounds like you want us to help with your homework

Comment: Don't use the double type to hold monetary values, use the decimal type instead.  You will likely have rounding errors if you use the double type.

Comment: I'm just going by what the extra credit said. I really want to learn this since it's my passion(I know VB is basic but I want to learn java and cobalt next semester to pursue a career with USSA...., but haven't been able to receive personal help at school with my mom's illness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres one fix:

```
Private dblInterest As Double
'...
Public Property InterestTotal As Double
    Get
        Return InterestTotal
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        InterestTotal = value   
        'expression recursively calls property interest total error
    End Set
End Property
```

Of course it recurses: `InterestTotal` is the name of the property, so when you try to return it in the Getter, it calls the Getter which invokes the Getter which...  The same with the Setter.

You probably meant to do what you did with the others, which is use the `backing field`:

```
Get
    Return dblInterest  
End Get
Set(value As Double)
    dblInterest  = value   
End Set
```

But there is more.  If you are using VS2010+ all you need is:

```
Public Property InterestTotal As Double
```

This is called an auto-implemented property.  With them, VS/VB creates a hidden backing field named `_InterestTotal` and does the getting and setting for you.   Finally, if this is money, `Decimal` might be a better data type to use.

Comment: I'm using vs12.  I would just use this code for all the other methods?

Comment: well I guess theyre functions since they have a set and return? i would just use this for all the methods? do i even need the separate classes? Thanks for for the info

Comment: "thanks" is usually in the form of click the checkmark; I am not sure what classes you are talking about - you only show one.

Comment: Private Function subtractWith() As Double
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

End Class



Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1<<<- for some reason the code didn't split up. agian i'm not used to this site.

Comment: code doesnt format in comments.  Start a new question with the specifics for whatever you are stuck on.  `subtractWith` is a function not a class.